# Pandas creating and populating a new dataframe efficiently (?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I'm creating a new DataFrame from scratch, but I'm not sure the way I'm doing it is the most efficient way.

I'm creating:

- column Never where 3070 = 1
- column Occasional 1100 = 1
- column Frequent 2200 = 1

I'm also creating a new column Police:

- where 70 rows = 1 and column Never = 1
- where 110 rows = 1 and column Occasional = 1
- where 220 rows = 1 and column Frequent = 1

Code:

```
# create dataframes for each column
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['NEVER']) for i in range(3070)],
          ignore_index=True)

df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['OCCASIONAL']) for i in range(1100)],
          ignore_index=True)

df3 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([1], columns=['FREQUENT']) for i in range(2200)],
          ignore_index=True)

# combine dataframes into one
frames = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(frames)

# reset index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['POLICE'] = 0.0

# replace police column values
df.loc[0:69,'POLICE']=1.0
df.loc[3071:3180,'POLICE']=1.0
df.loc[5271:5490,'POLICE']=1.0

# convert NaN into 0
values=(0.0)
df = df.fillna(value=values)
```

I think I've done it, but my code takes ages to process. Is it a normal thing as I'm creating 6000+ rows or my code is inefficient?

Comment: In my pc it takes only 1.26 sec. Maybe you should just restart the python or your pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an entirely different approach which is far more efficient.  Create a 2D list of your data, then turn it into a dataframe as one piece.

```
lst = []
for row in range(6370):
    lst.append([None, None, None, None])
    for col in range(4):
        if (col == 0 and row < 3070)\
                or (col == 1 and row >= 3070 and row < 1100)\
                or (col == 2 and row >= 4170)\
                or (col == 3 and row < 70)\
                or (col == 3 and row > 3070 and row <= 3180)\
                or (col == 3 and row > 5270 and row <= 5490):
            lst[row][col] = 1.0
        else:
            lst[row][col] = 0.0


df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ["NEVER", "OCCASIONAL", "FREQUENT", "POLICE"]
print(df)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can fill the column with ones and zeros using `np.ones()` and `np.zeros`. Using numpy you can obtain a substantial speedup.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframes for each column
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(3070), columns=['NEVER'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(1100), columns=['OCCASIONAL'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(2200), columns=['FREQUENT'])

# combine dataframes into one
frames = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(frames)

# reset index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['POLICE'] = np.zeros(6370)

# replace police column values
df.loc[0:69,'POLICE']=np.ones(70)
df.loc[3071:3180,'POLICE']=np.ones(110)
df.loc[5271:5490,'POLICE']=np.ones(220)

# convert NaN into 0
values=(0.0)
df = df.fillna(value=values)
```

In my machine - original code:

```
Process finished --- 2.513995409011841 seconds ---
```

Modified code:

```
Process finished --- 0.0069921016693115234 seconds ---
```